# Hosting Solr on GCP

Tags: solr, google-cloud-platform

We have a master-slave Solr setup and would like to put it on Google Cloud. How do you recommend that we do this? (VM, Kubernetes, etc)

The Solr setup is used by an e-commerce website to host product details.